# The meaning of '-' and '+' symbol when background processes are finished?

Tags: bash

When I am running background processes like(I have 9 files suffixed by phastcon):

```
for i in *.phastcon; do cut -f 2 $i >$i.value & done
```

After kicking the "Enter", I get the output in terminal showing background id and process id,

```
[1] 22917
[2] 22918
[3] 22919
[4] 22920
[5] 22921
[6] 22922
[7] 22923
[8] 22924
[9] 22925
```

But hen finished, I got

```
[7]   Done                    cut -f 2 $i > $i.value
[8]-  Done                    cut -f 2 $i > $i.value
[1]   Done                    cut -f 2 $i > $i.value
[2]   Done                    cut -f 2 $i > $i.value
[3]   Done                    cut -f 2 $i > $i.value
[4]   Done                    cut -f 2 $i > $i.value
[5]   Done                    cut -f 2 $i > $i.value
[6]-  Done                    cut -f 2 $i > $i.value
[9]+  Done                    cut -f 2 $i > $i.value
```

The results are all right.

But I can not understand what is the difference of **'-'** and **'+'** after the square.

Thank you for all helps!

Tong

Comment: A question: what is `$i.value`?

Comment: @neurino The output file

Comment: ok, I just guessed if there was in Bash some kind of dotted notation like javascript for variables :) `.value` is only the file extension ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the bash manpage, in the section "JOB CONTROL":

> In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the jobs command),
>   the current job is always flagged with a +, and the previous job with
>   a -.

This explains the + behind the `[9]`, because that was the last job started. It also explains the - behind `[8]` and `[6]`, because they were the previous jobs at the moment they finished (`[6]` was the previous job because `[7]` and `[8]` finished before it).

Comment: thanks.  i'd never spotted that in the bash man page, but it matches what i'd figured out long ago. nice to know that it's "official".

Comment: Thank you! Great answer. If the completion order of jobs is the same as the task allocation order, then no '-' will show. If a job costs longer time than the one started later, a '-' will add when finished. Do I get it? And also I wonder why these two operators are needed? Usually I will not care them.

Comment: @ct586 I find those useful when switching between jobs. The `+` indicated the last active job, the `-` the one before it. So if you started three jobs and did nothing about them, you'd have `[1] [2]- [3]+`. However, if you put job 2 in the foreground and the background again, you'd have `[1] [2]+ [3]-`. It can help determine which job was put in the foreground last, making it easier to switch. But there is more to the story, as the above answer shows and that's just one use case.

Comment: @Wojtek Rzepala Thanks for the wonderful example. My understand of '-' and '+' is wrong. I get it.

Comment: note also that the + and - can and will change position if you run several jobs and manually suspend/foreground them.  e.g. i tend to have lots of 'mutt -f /path/to/mbox' running and use ^Z to suspend & 'fg 1', 'fg 10', etc to switch between my frequently used mboxes.  i.e. they don't indicate the two most recently started jobs, but the current and previous jobs.

Comment: @Craig Sanders Thanks very much. I got it. BTW, ill manually suspend/foreground programs affect the final results?

Comment: that depends on the requirements of the program you're suspending, and whether suspending them will interfere with timing, data collection or similar.  many or even most  programs will be unaffected.